# How to add String with double Quotes on start and end of the string in Array using swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string, nsstring

I want to make this type of result :

```
{"":[["someId","someName"]]}
```

I m trying to make like this :

```
var fields:[AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()

for someId:String in Preferences.getAllIds(){
        let someName = Preferences.getAllNames(someId)
        let value = String(format: "%@,%@", someId,someName)
        var field:[String] = [String]()
        field.append(value)
        fields.append(field as AnyObject)
    }
let dict = ["": fields]
```

Output i m getting is:

```
{"":[["012345,test_name"]]}
```

AS you can see : there are double duotes before **012345** and after **test_name**

"012345,test_name"

But I want to add at start and end on both sides of the strings.

Like : "012345","test_name"

I have tried to achieve required output by this trick but failed unfortunately (don't know why this doesn't work) ... :(

```
value1 = value.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "\",\"")
```

Comment: It's because your did `let value = String(format: "%@,%@", someId,someName)`. But `[["someId","someName"]]` seems just to be a `[[String]]` (array of one array of strings).

Comment: it is because of your string format operation. what you want to do ?

Comment: @KKRocks I have to add both id and name at one array index with comma separated string, and both id and name should have double quotes at start and end

Comment: @Larme Then how should i do to get my required result

Comment: you can insert dictionary object instead of formatted string .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define it's array like this, Hope it will help you

```
var fields:[[String]] = [[String]]()

for someId:String in Preferences.getAllIds(){
    let someName = Preferences.getAllNames(someId)
    var arrValue : [String] = [String]()
    arrValue.append(someId)
    arrValue.append(someName)// ["someid","somename"]
    fields.append(arrValue as [String]) // [["someid","somename"]]
}
   let dict = ["": fields] // {"" : [["someid","somename"]]}
```

if you have static value Then you can make array like this

```
 let arrValue : [String] = ["\(someId!)","\(someName!)"]
```